# Create Callback from Python

Tags: javascript, java, python

I have a python script that gets called from some javascript code, that I have running. And when the python script is finished I want a call back to go to a Java program of mine, I was trying to make a html page and then check with that, but I am running the Java program locally and can't connect to the FTP?

How could this be accomplished?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is how the flow works

```
Java calls a javascript function in browser on my local machine ->
Javascript calls python with POST Request on my Server ->
I want a callback to Java to know when Python is done ->
So that Java can move on
```

Do you see know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from the command line you could use pipes `|` which will call the next command in line with the standard out of the first command. As follows:

`firstCommand | secondCommand`

So if your Python script writes to standard out you could invoke it from the command line, and have the Java execute from the command line also as the second command receiving it's input from standard in.

Comment: Thanks :-) too much front end

Comment: Not really what I am looking for but thanks, I need to not on the command line

Comment: Can't the Python script make calls to execute the Java directly on the command line by using the subprocess module?